# Solving recurrence with any tool (maple or other)

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, maple

I'm trying to automatically solve a recurrence formula with **more than one variable**.
Here is an example:

$$t(n,k) = t(n-1,k-1) + t(n-1,k)$$

The answer I expect is:
$$
t(n,k) = \binom{n}{k}
$$
When I try it with maple nothing happens, and it simply repeats what I wrote:

$$\text{rsolve}(f(n, k) = f(n - 1, k - 1) + f(n - 1, k), f(n, k))$$

Any way to automatically solve such recurrences? with maple? or other tool?

Comment: In **Maple 2020** `rsolve` works only with one variable. **Mathematica 12.1**  also not solve.All computer algebra systems,are limited in their capabilities.